# Could an attacker delete messages using an MMS exploit?

Tags: exploit, sms

My SMS messages are getting deleted. What I noticed is, that some number keeps sending me MMS messages, mostly pictures. Yes, I had the "accept MMS automatically" turned on my Samsung device to ON.

I've heard about [Stagefright](https://www.androidcentral.com/stagefright), but I didn't found any mentions *if* and **how** it could potentially delete my SMS - or even access my data (i.E. store a picture).

So the question is: Could an attacker do such thing as deleting message remotely?

Comment: check whether you phone has a "delete older message" feature turn on.

Comment: actually, all messages disappeared - even the new ones..

Comment: Plausible. Check your phone firmware date .